# Parallel Boxes - Identity

Tags: diagrams, boxes

how do I make this identity? Is there any way to type it without the use of tikz? Thanks
(My biggest problem is how I type the connected boxes)
[image]

Comment: Without TikZ? Do you mean without other drawing packages like PSTricks? It would be helpful if you started off by providing some code....

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Of course, this diagram is simple enough to be drawn with LaTeX's `picture` environment without any additional packages:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{picture}(250, 60)(0, -30)
  \put(0, 0){\line(1, 0){30}}
  \put(15, 2){\makebox(0, 0)[b]{$x(n)$}}
  \put(30, -20){\line(0, 1){40}}
  \put(30, -20){\line(1, 0){20}}
  \put(30, 20){\line(1, 0){20}}
  \put(50, -30){\framebox(30, 20){$h_2$}}
  \put(50, 10){\framebox(30, 20){$h_1$}}
  \put(80, -20){\line(1, 0){20}}
  \put(80, 20){\line(1, 0){20}}
  \put(100, -20){\line(0, 1){40}}
  \put(100, 0){\line(1, 0){30}}
  \put(115, 2){\makebox(0, 0)[b]{$y(n)$}}
  \put(145, 0){\makebox(0, 0){$\equiv$}}
  \put(160, 0){\line(1, 0){30}}
  \put(175, 2){\makebox(0, 0)[b]{$x(n)$}}
  \put(190, -10){\framebox(30, 20){$h(n)$}}
  \put(220, 0){\line(1, 0){30}}
  \put(235, 2){\makebox(0, 0)[b]{$y(n)$}}
\end{picture}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

For fun, a version for plain TeX (can also be used in LaTeX), which
limits itself to basic box and `\kern` commands:

```
\hbox{%
  \raise1ex\hbox to 30pt{\hss$x(n)$\hss}%
  \kern-30pt
  \vrule height.2pt depth.2pt width30pt
  \kern-.2pt
  \vrule depth20.2pt height20.2pt width.4pt
  \kern-.4pt
  \vrule depth20.2pt height-19.8pt width20.8pt
  \kern-20.8pt
  \vrule depth-19.8pt height20.2pt width20.8pt
  \kern-.4pt
  \vrule depth30.2pt height-9.8pt width.4pt
  \kern-.4pt
  \vrule depth-9.8pt height30.2pt width.4pt
  \kern-.4pt
  \vrule depth30.2pt height-29.8pt width30.8pt
  \kern-30.8pt
  \vrule depth10.2pt height-9.8pt width30.8pt
  \kern-30.8pt
  \vrule depth-9.8pt height10.2pt width30.8pt
  \kern-30.8pt
  \vrule depth-29.8pt height30.2pt width30.8pt
  \kern-30.8pt
  \lower20pt\vbox to 0pt{\vss\hbox to 30.8pt{\hss$h_2$\hss}\vss}%
  \kern-30.8pt
  \raise20pt\vbox to 0pt{\vss\hbox to 30.8pt{\hss$h_1$\hss}\vss}%
  \kern-.4pt
  \vrule depth30.2pt height-9.8pt width.4pt
  \kern-.4pt
  \vrule depth-9.8pt height30.2pt width.4pt
  \kern-.4pt
  \vrule depth20.2pt height-19.8pt width20.8pt
  \kern-20.8pt
  \vrule depth-19.8pt height20.2pt width20.8pt
  \kern-.4pt
  \vrule depth20.2pt height20.2pt width.4pt
  \raise1ex\hbox to 30pt{\hss$y(n)$\hss}%
  \kern-30pt
  \vrule height.2pt depth.2pt width30pt
  \kern1em
  \vbox to 0pt{\vss\hbox{$\equiv$}\vss}%
  \kern1em
  \raise1ex\hbox to 30pt{\hss$x(n)$\hss}%
  \kern-30pt
  \vrule height.2pt depth.2pt width30pt
  \kern-.2pt
  \vrule depth10pt height10pt width.4pt
  \kern-.4pt
  \vrule depth10.2pt height-9.8pt width30.8pt
  \kern-30.8pt
  \vrule depth-9.8pt height 10.2pt width30.8pt
  \kern-30.6pt
  \vbox to 0pt{\vss\hbox to 30pt{\hss$h(n)$\hss}\vss}%
  \kern-.2pt
  \vrule depth10pt height10pt width.4pt
  \kern-.2pt
  \raise1ex\hbox to 30pt{\hss$y(n)$\hss}%
  \kern-30pt
  \vrule height.2pt depth.2pt width30pt
}
\bye
```

> [image: Result]